# Stack Overflow Footer on zoom

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, footer

I'm just curious, why is the Stack Overflow footer misaligned on zooming?
When I had the same issue on my site, I came to stackoverflow for a solution, and I saw the same problem here. Is it a browser rendering method that can't be controlled?

Here I'm providing a screenshot of it..

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Because it was not designed with zooming in mind?

Comment: Works for me (tm). FF14

Comment: Zooming isn't the correct description here, it's under-sizing the page and then scrolling to the right.

Comment: @Oded Might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're not going to fix this, it's too minor and rather difficult to reliably fix for all themes on all browsers.