# Profile Reputation Graph Bug in IE 10

Tags: bug, status-norepro, reputation-graph, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

As the title says, there seems to be a bug in the profile reputation graph. This is in regards to the lower of the two graphs, and happens in IE 10.

The bug is that I am unable to change the range by dragging across the chart.

It seems to work in FF and Chrome on the same machine. It also works in IE 9 on another machine (Windows 2008 R2).

My non-working environment, more specifically, is: Windows 7 SP1, IE 10.0.9200.16618 (with update 10.0.6).  **Update** - The bug seems to only happen with a non-standard zoom setting (125% or above) in IE10.  I did try non-standard browser zooms in FF and Chrome on the same machine, as well as IE9 on my other machine and these all work.

Here's a picture of the graph on Stack Overflow, and the bit that is not change-able/ drag-able:

[image: Rep Graph]

Comment: The freehand circle is not red.

Comment: Yes, and the circle is horribly drawn too. I guess I don't quite understand your comment. Did I break protocol by using blue?

Comment: Yes. All freehand circles must be red! We can forgive you this time, but next time you will have to answer to the ringleaders of Meta :)

Comment: Reproduced on IE10 with non-100% zoom.

Comment: Well, the site doesn't really work 100% with zoom, for example see [this declined bug report about footer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144477/152859) - just make sure you're at 100% zoom level and things should work fine.

Comment: @Undo - [This post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47640/216322) does not mention anything about *red* circles. Also, [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775) discusses circles, and does not mention red. However, it does say "**it has become customary to give cheap upvotes to users who painstakingly draw free hand and not rely on lazy shape tools that give soulless circles devoid of personality.**"

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - It's not a big deal to me. I only figured out after I filed the report that it was a zoom issue.

Comment: @chuex yep. By the way, Mr. Undo is joking, if you didn't understand.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - yes, got the joke about the red. The important part is the bold bit :)

Comment: Well, my +1 is for the report itself not circles. :)