# UI bug in favicon sprite?

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, sidebar, zoom

Looks like there's a small design bug with the icons in the favicon sprite in the Hot Network Questions section of the page (Maybe they're too close togther? )

I'm using opera 18.0 on Windows 7 (at 110% zoom) <-- Thanks @Shadow Wizard

[image]

Comment: What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: No problem on Chrome, Firefox or Safari on my Mac, all latest versions.

Comment: hmm that's odd. Usually opera renders like chrome. So maybe it's an opera bug?

Comment: Reproduced with 110% zoom in Chrome. @Danield are you sure there's no zoom? Firefox has a new feature of "auto zoom" based on screen resolution, maybe Opera got such thing too now?

Comment: @ShadowWizard oops, you're right. I was on 110% zoom (not sure how I got there). I'll edit the question to fix this. Hmm, so would this still be considered a bug?

Comment: @Danield so I fear it's not a bug, zoom tend to break lots of things. Will look for some official stand on this. OK, see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144477/stack-overflow-footer-on-zoom (Oded's comment is quite clear :))

Comment: declining as this is a zooming issue.

Comment: No problem. When I asked the question, I thought I was on on 100% zoom.