# Badge icons are cropped

Tags: bug, design, badges

There is a minor bug with badges display.

[image]

Close-up:
[image]

I'm using Chrome browser on Mac.
I tried to change `.badge1, .badge2, .badge3` width to `7px` instead of `6px` and it fixes the issue.

Update: I realized that I was at scale of 125%. The issue appears and disappears randomly if I go from 125% to 200% of zoom.

Comment: What is your zoom level on the page? If you have [such icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQBNh.png) in the address bar it means the zoom is not 100% thus design will break.

Comment: @ShadowWizard good point! I was at 125%. Not sure that design should break anyway. Just checked. If I go from 100% to 200% by pressing cmd '+' the issue appears and disappears for even and odd steps.
Updated the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UI bug in favicon sprite?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215850/ui-bug-in-favicon-sprite)

Comment: When at 200% zoom, the site thinks you're on a retina device and update itself accordingly, so it works. anyway, SE does not support all zoom levels, see the developer comments on the other similar report.